# What is the Lua language used in Conky script?

Tags: crunchbang, programming, conky, lua

I've been experimenting with Linux on a spare PC using Crunchbang so that I can try changing things and tinker. The Conky system monitor is fun to work with and changes are immediately seen, so it's a great hands-on educational tool. I've read that it uses the Lua language which I've never heard of. Usually, it's python or perl or C++.  What is the Lua language and is it worthwhile to learn it for beginners to programming?

Comment: What part of the Wikipedia article don't you understand?

Comment: I'm a newbie and definitely on the wrong site - how can I compete with someone as advanced as you? Your folks must be so proud.

Comment: Lua and it's relation to Conky are discussed in the wiki on the Conky github site... https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Lua

Answer (score 3):

Lua is a really tiny programming language. It's written in C and it's **GOOD**. Take a look at the "Programming in Lua" - online book on http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html.

Lua is a perfect tool for embedding scripts in otherwise C/C++ applications. So with Lua built into an executable like conky (which I didn't know of) you can make it very adaptable.